# VMR9 aspect ratio mode

Tags: directshow, video-processing, renderer

I want to disable the letter-boxing of a `VMR9` with three input streams. The aspect ratio mode was correctly set to `VMR_ARMODE_NONE` with function `IVMRWindowlessControl9::SetAspectRatioMode`. But I can't get the `VMR9` to give up letter-boxing. The black bars are always shown.

Does anybody now what could be the reason for this behavior?

BTW: With `IVMRAspectRatioControl9::SetAspectRatioMode` I can't disable the black bars too.

Comment: How do you expect "no bars" mode? Transparent area where you have letter boxing with AR enforcement enabled? This is not going to work out. But what you can do is disable letter boxing AND update video position respectively so that there is no transparent are needed at all.

Comment: If I change the AR mode in the vrmplayer exsample of the SDK change from VMR_ARMODE_LETTER_BOX to VMR_ARMODE_NONE the AR is not kept any longer. The video is stretched to fit the video output window. This what I want. - And yes: if disabling of letter boxing works fine I want to control the video position by my self. But currently I have letter boxes all the time.

Comment: So, VMRPlayer sample with VMR_ARMODE_NONE replaces AR enforcement with stretching to fill the entire position. You seem to be able to do the same in your application too, does it only work in the sample for you?

Comment: Yes, the sample behaves as expected. My own application not. I still looking for the difference. I hope there is an idea why the application is forced to letter-box.